# Position: fixed and transform: translateZ

Tags: css, position, overflow, viewport, fixed

Sometimes my sidebar with `position: fixed` scrolls with page. It happens only in Chrome. I think something wrong happening with viewport (I also have lazy loading implemented, maybe it impacts on viewport). I decided to apply `transform: translateZ(0)` to the sidebar element. Issue seems to be gone but I can not understand how `transform` impacts on elements with fixed position?

I have read a lot of information about how it works before asking this question but I can't understand how it solves the problem, maybe there's a need to fix elements which cause viewport overflow? Thanks a lot and sorry for my English.

Comment: translateZ doesn't work directly with position but that doesn't mean they won't impact each other because it's all based on context. It's best if you post your code so we can explain what is happening in context.

Answer (score 1):

`position: fixed`  will always position the element relative to the initial window viewport, except when one of the element's ancestors has a transform property, in which case that ancestor behaves like the new viewport:

```
.container {
    transform: translateZ(0); // the "new" viewport
    
    .child {
        position: fixed;
        top: 1rem; // 1rem relatively to .container
    }
}
```

So when you gave the container a `transform` property, it acted as the `relative` container to the `fixed` child and sorted your issue.

Check out [Mozilla's CSS/position docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) - they explain the subject well.